# Ajax conditional response not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Never had any problems with jQuery ajax, but I am stuck on this very weird problem. Here is my ajax snippet:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'xxx',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response == "1") {
        alert("ONE");
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

the php echos either "1" or "2" and it does so successfully in the console. But even when the php script echos "1", the alert saying "ONE" does not appear, I am completely lost on this!

Comment: are you sure it's not returning it inside a JSON object or, including some whitespace or something? Show us the PHP code and/or the exact, full raw response. Also what's the contentType of the response?

Comment: Check  `console.log(response);` what it is showing in console ?

Comment: Try removing any whitespace from the response using `if (response.trim() == "1")`. It's for this reason that JSON or XML is a better format for returning data.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This solved my issue, thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When returning a plaintext response from an AJAX call you need to be careful you exclude any whitespace when checking the returned value. To do this, use `trim()`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'xxx',
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.trim() == "1") { // note trim() here
      console.log("ONE");
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
});
```

It's for this reason that using a serialised format for the response is a much better idea. Try looking in to JSON or XML instead.

Also note the use of `console.log()` for debugging is preferred over `alert()` as it does not coerce data types.